# Why would I want to delete build/ directory?

Tags: flutter

(New to Flutter/Dart/Android)

In console just did:

```
C:\Users\lordnull>flutter help clean
Delete the build/ directory.
```

Just wondering why we would want to delete a project's build directory (using "flutter clean")? Does it help cure some transient Flutter problem? If so what?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The content of the build directory is updated incrementally depending on configuration or source changes for performance reasons because a full rebuild every time would take way too much time.

The dependencies can be quite complex and some changes don't invalidate all parts in `build/` that need to be rebuilt after such changes.

This can lead to a corrupt build output.

`flutter clean` purges the build output and the next build action will rebuild everything from scratch.

That's not unique to Flutter. Most build systems offer such a clean step to ensure a build is not influenced by artifacts from previous build actions.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. To be clear, when I press the green triangle "Run" button in Android Studio that is doing a  build, right? Also, how would I know when I need to do a "flutter clean"? What do we look for to know when to rebuild everything from scratch?

Comment: Yes, to run the app it needs to be built first. You shouldn't need `flutter clean`. Usually it is used when the app doesn't run as expected and the unexpected behavior can't be explained by your custom code. Usually it's a Flutter bug if you need `flutter clean` but because of the involved complexity it's often impossible to track down what exactly went wrong and therefore impossible to fix. `flutter clean` is required much less frequently than for example 6 months ago and should continue to decrease.