# When to use the command "flutter clean"?

Tags: flutter, memory, heap-memory

I always use run 'flutter clean' most times before running my app because of memory size. Is this the correct thing to do? And at what point should one run 'flutter clean' in their console terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would I want to delete build/ directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612454/why-would-i-want-to-delete-build-directory)

Answer (score 5):

`flutter clean` deletes build-cache which is in the /build folder.

An example of when to use it would be when you make significant changes to platform-specific files in the /ios and /android folder.

Take a look at the Github issue that led to the implementation of the `flutter clean` command [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10783).

Answer (score 2):

I use flutter clean when there are any bugs in the build process. Mainly when there are no errors, but project cannot build